# Free portable instant messaging & audio/video calls for Windows, web, Android and J2ME

Tags: windows, android, web-apps, chat, phone

**EDIT:** I've changed my requirements. Also, Linphone didn't help me.

I'm looking for a free, cross-platform, portable instant messaging service with which I can:

- Send instant messages
- Have emoticons
- Send files and photos
- Audio call and video call (at least on PC and Android)
- Record chatlogs (at least on PC)
- Not take up so much RAM like Skype sometimes to the level of inoperability

...on these platforms:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit
- Android 4.0 or above
- Java 2 Micro Edition (like for Sony Ericsson K510i and above, including C510 and W705)
- Ubuntu Linux
- FreeBSD

...either via:

- Opera Mini web browser on mobiles
- Opera Web Browser for PC
- At least one of the standard browsers for Ubuntu and FreeBSD
- Application

Existing, but obsolete IM was
Windows Live Messenger + eBuddy which worked for all Windows, Androids, Java enabled phones and even web browsers. I could stay logged in on my PC with Windows Live Messenger to log chats while being outside and chatting on my J2ME phone using eBuddy. eBuddy was however limited from sending files, pictures and calling. Windows Live Messenger was the best until Microsoft bought Skype and all WLM users had to use it or download Messenger Reviver

Do you know if any other exists?

Comment: What about [nimbuzz](http://www.nimbuzz.com/en/) ?

Comment: I've had it in 2011, but now it requires registration via phone number. Can I register without the phone number?

Comment: Take a look at clients supporting the Jabber protocol then, like [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) (Java base, cross-platform). Related: [Gratis software for cross-platform VoIP (replacement for Skype)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17637/185) / [Free/Libre voice & video chat alternative to Skype?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/243/185)

Comment: Instead of changing the requirements you should have asked a new question.

Comment: I thought it would be a duplicate then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of all portable messengers can be located at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_clients.

It is broken down by features, OS, etc. Anything you need will be located here.

Comment: Does it support J2ME? I've read on a programmer's blog that the programmer failed to code a Hangouts client.

Comment: @Foxcat385 Doesn't look like it now that I'm looking... Perhaps this chart will help out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_clients Not sure if you have seen it yet.

Comment: I see now. Thank you! Can you just edit your answer to show the link you just wrote so that I can approve your answer?

Comment: @Foxcat385 No problem :) Glad I could help. I edited my answer to show the link.

Answer (score 3):

If you can do without emoticons, **[Linphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linphone)** would be worth a look:

[image: Linphone] [image: Linphone]
<sup>*Linphone* on Android (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.linphone); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I'm using this on Android and am quite satisfied – though I by far don't use all the features you've requested, so I cannot give my opinion on all of them. It's said to be one of the best when it comes to video quality.

Let's see how it meets your requirements:

- **Send instant messages:** Yes.
- **Have emoticons:** Not that I've found them, so probably no. Smileys are "converted", though, as the screenshots show.
- **Send files and photos:** photos definitely (see second screenshot), for files I'm not sure
- **Audio call and video call:** Yes.
- **Record chatlogs:** Didn't try that yet, but I'm pretty positive here.
- **Not take up so much RAM like Skype sometimes to the level of inoperability:** Never encountered that.
- **Supports platforms...:** Except for the Java one, yes. Not sure whether there are solutions to include that one as well.

*Linphone* is fully SIP compatible, so it can be used with any SIP provider. They run their own service, though, so you could use that as comparable to the "Skype registry" as "central point". *Linphone* is free and open source (the Android app e.g. is also available via *F-Droid*).

For additional details, you might wish to visit the [Wikipedia page on Linphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linphone), and also the [Linphone homepage](https://www.linphone.org/).

---

For an alternative, **[Fring](http://www.fring.com/)** might be worth a look as well: multi-platform, multi-protocol (in the past even supported Skype). There's an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fring) available ("Free Calls, Group Calls, Texting, Video, Group Video, and more!"), but I found no detailed information on other platforms other than it's being "cross platform".

Comment: I've had problems connecting with one friend over this service. Is there a tutorial for this?

Comment: Have you tried our friend [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=linphone+tutorial)? :) First hit is a [youtube tutorial on Linphone configuration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1ngm6JOUF0), second the [list of tutorials on the Linphone site](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__tutorials.html), third a [user guide for Linphone on Linux](http://www.linphone.org/user-guide.html). Save me listing the remaining 7 links of the first result page, will you? #D